# Convert chain of characters with JavaScript (not working anymore?)

Tags: javascript

I do not understand why I can't simply convert my chain of characters while it should work (when I wanna convert a **single character** it works but when I wanna convert a **chain of characters** it just won't). Did I miss anything? Thank you!

```js
var kkma_conv = {
  // comments blablabla
  '시/EPH': '',
}

function conversion_final(kkma) {
  var roman = kkma_conv[kkma];
  if (roman) {
    return roman;
  } else {
    return kkma;
  }
}
```

```html
<script>
  function printconvert(form2) {
    var testin = document.form2.entree.value;
    var res = conversion_final(testin);
    document.form2.sortie.value = res.replace(/&#39;/g, "'");
  }
</script>

<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <FORM NAME="form2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div align="left">Insert text :</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="entree" value="input" rows="30" cols="75" style="font-size:12px"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td style="padding:5px">
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="bouton" VALUE="CONVERT" onClick="printconvert(form2)">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div align="left">Conversion :</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="sortie" value="output" rows="30" cols="75" style="font-size:12px"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </FORM>
</table>
```

Comment: Try changing to: if (roman !== undefined) {

Comment: thanks for your help! your method works but that's only if I write exactly "시/EPH" (when I write "시/EPH ", with a space after, it isn't converted again)

Comment: @user2911849 if you add a space at the end, `kkma_conv` will not have the property and hence in the `conversion_final` function, `roman` will be undefined and it will return the input again.

Answer (score 2):

`conversion_final("시/EPH")` will return `"시/EPH"` because `kkma_conv[kkma]` is emptry string which is falsy, hence it returns the input.

Also as far as i know `&#39;` is maybe html syntax for some symbol but not in javascript, i am unsure what you intend to do there (maybe not a problem).

Comment: Thank for your answer but I'm not sure to know why it is empty as you say. P.S. &#39; is not useful in here because the input doesn't contain a " ' ", yet it might contain some later

Comment: @user2911849 because it is defined as such in your code: `'시/EPH': ''`. Note again that in javascript, `/&#39;/g.test("'") === false`

Comment: I got it! thanks! I made if false to delete it ; I think I know exactly what the problem is (but I don't know the solution to it...) -> the script only accepts to convert single characters (I tried 'q' : 'ga', and it works while 'qq' : 'ga', returns 'qq')

Answer (score 1):

`''` as a boolean expression will be evaluated to false. So, that if-statement will fail and else-statement will be executed. Therefore, you should re-write your `conversion_final` function as follows.

```
function conversion_final(kkma) {
    if (kkma_conv.hasOwnProperty(kkma)) { 
        return kkma_conv[kkma];
    } 
    else { 
        return kkma; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your edited alternative solution is a much less buggy way. If someone were to provide a string like 'toString' then the `replace` method would throw an error in the last line of `printconvert`.

Comment: it works, thanks for your help Frogatto (it only works for the occurrence of one "시/EPH"; what if my corpora has several "시/EPH" like  "시/EPH adakad 시/EPH"?)

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I was mentioning it in jest as a large number of people make that mistake hence the [Princess Bride quote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wujVMIYzYXg). :D